# Can i use Twillio number as receiver PayPal adaptive payments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, twilio, twilio-php

I have an application that use PayPal adaptive payments api and live in country where PayPal doesn't support payment by phone number. 
Can i use USA Twillio numbers for testing this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's nothing on Twilio's Ts&Cs saying you can't use a number from another country for whatever purpose as long as it doesn't infringe any laws or goes against the Ts&Cs of another company.

So in theory, there's nothing wrong with you using a Twilio number as long as Paypal is ok with that. I'm assuming you just want to use a US number to verify and test that payments go through right? If that's the case, I think it's OK, but would still check with Paypal to make sure they are OK with that.